# .NET webservice attemp to print on a network printer not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I am working on a c# web service using .net framwork 4.0
and I have a file (print.exe) which executes printing, the file works when I double click it manually, it prints, but when using the webservice it give an error that No printer installed.

this the code of the webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
        public String Print_In_Kitchen(Int32 OrderID, String Lang)
        {
            System.Security.SecureString secPass = new System.Security.SecureString();
            string paswd = "96321";
            for (int i = 0; i < paswd.Length; i++)
            {
                secPass.AppendChar(paswd[i]);
            }

            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\EXE_Print.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"" + OrderID + " " + Lang + " " + "\"" + ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString + "\"";
            proc.StartInfo.UserName = "omar";
            proc.StartInfo.Password = secPass;
            proc.StartInfo.Domain = "Futec";
            proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            proc.Start();
            string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            proc.WaitForExit();

            return s;
}
```

I have searched for a solution but haven't found any useful link or explanation for this, saw this question here but with no answer:[pdf print through .net process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195519/pdf-print-through-net-process)
and I am new to .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut feeling is that the User that the Service is running as, doesn't have access to that printer.

You could try changing `StartInfo.UseShellExecute` to `true` but I would also check the permissions of your services user.

Comment: ok I will try it now, and the user is the admin of the network itself

Comment: What happens if you log in as this user and run the console app directly?

Comment: I finally got it to work with help of my boss of course, turned out to be a security issue, so we  tried to work around the permission thing, by using a web service listener which is a windows application that triggers the exe file which sends the file to the printer, so the web service doesnt directly access the exe file.